# If I copy the world folder while the server is running, will the copied world be corrupted?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I plan on creating a copy of my world every now and then. Is it okay to copy the `world` folder or run a `git push` while the server is running? As in, is there going to be any consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The world file constantly updates on a set interval. Servers do not perform any special action on a world when the session is ended (so worlds aren't corrupted on a non-intentional shutdown), so the world file should not be corrupted.